# Resize bytes in python

Tags: python, file

I read file from disk and in case if its size less than 256 bytes I need to extend it. Some think like:

```
data = open("test.txt", "rb").read()
if ( len(data) < 256  ):
    data.resize( 256 ) # Fill with zeroes or something
```

But since bytes is immutable type there is no anything like resize method.

I don't need to modify original file, I need len(data) to be not less than 256 for further processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extend it with spaces:

```
data = open("test.txt", "rb").read()
padding_character = ' '  # space
data += padding_character*(256-len(data))
```

Comment: `padding_character = b'\0'` is probably more what was intended.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zfill` for str and bytes alike:

```
data = b'abc'
data = data.zfill(20) # or 256 in your case
print(data)
# b'00000000000000000abc'
```

Note: If your data length is already 256 (or whatever value you use) or more, `zfill` will return the original object.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.zfill

Comment: But did they want to fill on the left or on the right? And with a literal `'0'` or with the null byte `b'\0'`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's indeed not clear, but my answer fits the vague "``Fill with zeroes or something``" requirement from the question.

Comment: I was just pointing out the ambiguity, not dinging you for it. But since it's a binary file I would have made different assumptions.

Comment: I need filling new data from right not left, I think ljust is what I am looking for